# Is there a way to prevent display turning off?

Tags: python, linux, gtk, fullscreen, power-management

I'm writing a presentation software. I control the presentation on my primary screen, and I display it on the second screen. If the image on the second screen doesn't change after a while, my computer turns off the second screen. Off course, I could simply disable powersaving features on my computer, but what I'd like would be to have my software tell the OS not to turn off the second display when it displays fullscreen on it. How can I achieve that? I'm on Linux, and using Python and GTK3.